# Prolog: Reversed list -- can't find the error

Tags: list, prolog, reverse

I want to write a `reverse/2` function. This is my code and I cannot figure out where the error is.

```
rev([]).
rev([H|T],X):-rev(T,X),append(T,H,_).
```

The output:

```
rev ([1,2,3,4], X).
false.
```

Comment: Notice that there is not meaning to `rev([]).`, for an empty list it should be `rev([],[]).`

Comment: you meant `rev([],[]). rev([H|T],X):-rev(T,R),append(R,[H],X).`.

Comment: @DennisVash I meant the rev([]). as an exit condition when the list is emtpy. Why isn't that working?

Comment: @tgtrmr It never called... Check Will’s comment if you want implements reverse with append/3

Comment: @tgtrmr `rev([])` is not working because it is never called. It is never called because all of your calls to `rev` are given 2 arguments, not one. And Prolog doesn't support "default" arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`rev(?List1,?List2)` is `true` when elements of `List2` are in **reversed order** compared to `List1`

```
rev(Xs, Ys) :-
    rev(Xs, [], Ys, Ys).

rev([], Ys, Ys, []).
rev([X|Xs], Rs, Ys, [_|Bound]) :-
    rev(Xs, [X|Rs], Ys, Bound).
```

Output:

```
?- rev([1,2,3,4],X).
X = [4, 3, 2, 1].

?- rev([3,4,a,56,b,c],X).
X = [c, b, 56, a, 4, 3].
```

**Explanation of `rev/4`**

On call `rev([X|Xs](1), Rs(2), Ys(3), [_|Bound](4))`

1. `[X|Xs]`(1) - `List1`, the input list in our case (we can either call `rev(Z,[3,2,1]).`)
2. `Rs`(2) - `ResultList` is a helping list, we start with an empty list and on every recursive call we push (adding as head member) a member from `[X|Xs](1)`.
3. `Ys`(3) - `List2`, the output list (reversed list of `List1`)
4. `[_|Bound]`(4) - `HelpingList` for bounding the length of `Ys`(3) (for iterating "length of `Ys`" times).

On every recursion call `rev(Xs(5), [X|Rs](6), Ys(3), Bound(7)).`,

we push head member `X` (`[X|Xs]`(1)) to the front of `Rs` (`[X|Rs]`(6)),
and iterating the next member of `Ys` (`Bound`(7),`[_|Bound]`(4)).

The recursion ends when `rev([](9), Ys(10), Ys(3), [](12)).` is `true`.

Every `[X|Xs]`(1) (now the list is empty `[]`(9)) member moved in reversed order to `Ys`(10), we bounded the size of `Ys(3)` (using `[_|Bound](4)` and now it's empty `[]`(12)).

---

Notice that `append/3` - `append(?List1, ?List2, ?List1AndList2).`
was wrong used in your code, `append(T,H,_)` when `H` is not a `List2` (it's the head member of the list).

Example use of `append/2` and `append/3`:

```
?- append([[1,2],[3]],X).  % append/2 - Concatenate a list of lists.
X = [1, 2, 3].

?- append([4],[5],X).      % append/3 - X is the concatenation of List1 and List2

X = [4, 5].
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations for the meaning of each argument to `rev/4`?

Comment: @WillNess added some explanation

Comment: thanks. so Ys is the reverse of Xs, and their lengths are the same. Also, I guess the order of clauses of `rev/4` is important for the generative use case, `rev(A,B)`, to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not place a space between the functor name rev and the argument list. Usually this gives a syntax error:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.7.1)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.

?- rev ([1,2,3],X).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: rev
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  ([1,2,3],X) .
```

Otherwise I think the rev/4 solution aims at a bidirectional solution. If you don't need this, and want to go for an accumulator solution that doesn't leave a choice point, you can try:

```
reverse(X, Y) :-
   reverse2(X, [], Y).

reverse2([], X, X).
reverse2([X|Y], Z, T) :-
   reverse2(Y, [X|Z], T).
```